# Impossible to download old version source in maven (IntelliJ)

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm trying to import spark-core_2.11 (version 2.3.3) with maven in IntelliJ.
But I can't download spark sources for 2.11_2.3.3.
I have to use 2.11_2.3.3, not other version.

[image]

In this link,
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.3.3
there must vbe 2.11_2.3.3 version...
Below is my pom.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>secret.App</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>test</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>




  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.jungwoo.netmarble.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <filters>
              <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>

                <excludes>

                  <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>

                  <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>

                  <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>

                </excludes>
              </filter>
            </filters>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>




        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>


        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.jungwoo.netmarble.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>

            </archive>
          </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>copy-dependencies</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>lib/</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: well the source file is in maven central: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/2.3.3/ - IntelliJ sometimes struggles with sources if behind a proxy. Could you try "mvn dependency:sources" on the command line once?

Comment: I understand that you want to use the linked dependency in your POM. But I don't understand the problem you get. What did you do and what error did you get?

Comment: @JFMeier I uploaded new picture! sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by properly setting proxy.